# "scipy.optimize.minimize" staying in domain of positive real numbers?

Tags: python, scipy

So I have a function that I wish to minimize, defined as:

```
def b(x):  
    return -(2*x[0]**2-10*x[0] + x[1]**2 - 2*x[1] + 2*x[2]**2 - 3*x[2])/1000
```

Then I define my constraints and bounds:

Constraints

```
J = 14000
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: J -(2*x[0] + 5*x[1] + 3*x[2])},
       {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 0.4*(x[0]+x[1]+x[2]) - x[0]},
    {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 0.4*(x[0]+x[1]+x[2]) - x[1]},
    {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 0.4*(x[0]+x[1]+x[2]) - x[2]})
```

Bounds

```
x_bounds = (0.0 , None)
y_bounds = (0.0 , None)
z_bounds = (0.0, None)
bnds = [x_bounds, y_bounds, z_bounds]
```

When I go to run my code, if I set the initial values of my independent variables to be 0.1, such that,

```
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(b, [0.1], method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds,
                    constraints=cons)
```

It yields the following: [First results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp94x.png)

However, if I define the initial values of my independent variables to equal 1.5, such that,

```
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(b, [1.5], method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds,
                    constraints=cons)
```

It yields the following: [Second results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06cbd.png)

The second result is much more coherent with what I am trying to do (maximize a benefit function with independent variables representing units to produce of different goods).

Is it possible that the algorithm, once it begins to iterate with 0.1 as initial condition, obtains a positive real number value for the objective function, and as it continues to iterate, it concludes the iteration process once it hits a number that is practically zero; instead of continuing the iterations and evaluating whether the function goes into the domain of negative real numbers?

Comment: Those optimizers cannot guarantee [global optima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_and_minimum) (which is NP-hard when the problem is non-convex) and even guaranteering local convergence is quite some work (and some implementations might not even provide this). If your problem has local-optima which are not global-optima, even a perfect local-optimal optimizer would fail like in your example for *some* intitial values. In practice, you might use a multi-start approach where you just randomize your initial vector N times and pick the best result.

Comment: I guess your problem is indeed *not so nice*: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hessian%28-%282*x**2-10*x+%2B+y**2+-+2*y+%2B+2*z**2+-+3*z%29%29) -> looks like a concave quadratic-programming problem to me. See also [some semi-relevant discussion on scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/minimizing-a-negative-definite-quadratic-function-with-specified-bounds)